# Computing least squares error

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I have a mathematica subroutine setup that computes the least squares approximation as follows

```
uniform[n_, knot_, data_] := (m = Length[data] - 1; 
vandermonde = 
Table[BernsteinBasis[n, j - 1, knot[[i]]], {i, 1, m + 1}, {j, 1, 
  n + 1}]; 
bez = LinearSolve[Transpose[vandermonde].vandermonde, 
 Transpose[vandermonde].data]; dplot = ListPlot[data]; 
points = Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Point[bez]}]; 
bplot = ListLinePlot[bez]; 
curve[t_] := Sum[BernsteinBasis[n, i, t]*bez[[i + 1]], {i, 0, n}]; 
cplot = ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}]; 
Show[{cplot, points, bplot, dplot}]);
```

I now need to compute the least squares error for the set of equations and return the total,min,max and average error.

I went through this example in order to understand the concept - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Motivational_example

I am unsure as to how to proceed with performing this computation in mathematica as I'm still a newbie.

Comment: Same code found here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108633/subroutine-for-chord-length-parametrization-using-knots

Comment: (1) What do all the plots have to do with your question? (2)  Re "how to proceed with performing this computation" -- what computation, exactly?  There is probably enough information to figure it out, but you're asking everybody to do a lot of work just to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelE2 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=LinearSolve+vandermonde

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to calculate the errors in a simple case. `a` is a matrix and `b` is a vector. You find the `x` that minimizes the least square error and then calculate the errors `err`. Then find the `Total`, `Min`, `Max`, `Mean`.

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
x = LeastSquares[a, b]
err = a.x - b;
{Total[err], Min[err], Max[err], Mean[err]}
```